# Ways to add the [Good] Descriptor to Spells for Arcane Spellcaster

Tags: dnd-3.5e, dungeons-and-dragons, character-creation, optimization

The 'Consecrate Spell' feat from Book of Exalted Deeds adds the [Good] descriptor to spells cast. Is there another way to achieve this for arcane spellcasters, e.g. as a prestige class feature?

The reason I'm asking is the 'Spell Focus: Good' (also from Book of Exalted Deeds), which is the only (non-greater) Spell Focus feat that gives +2 to DC. Having a cheap way of adding [good] has obvious benefits in the combination.

For energy, there is the energy substitution feat from Complete Mage, but what is there for [good]?

Comment: Is there a specific character you are trying to set up with it?  Because if you're willing to pump levels into a prestige class, but not throw away a feat you're going to get anyway, then it seems like more trouble than it's worth.

Comment: But if he/she manages to apply the descriptor in a consistent manner, then the +2 DC is added to every spell, not just the ones of a single school.

Comment: For your information, Spell Focus: Good was nerfed down to provide only a +1 bonus in Complete Divine. See page 84.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found the answer myself, by chance:

Aligned Spellcaster, alternative class feature from Dragon 357, p88:

"Choose an alignment component you have that is not neutral. Spells you cast gain the appropriate alignment descriptor unless they already have the opposite alignment descriptor."